# SELECT tab options selected not showing highlight after select other option and re select the selected option

Tags: html

Currently I develop a system will auto select options from list depend of user input. The issue I facing is once the `selected='selected'` attribute removed and use js re-add again the layout will not showing highlight even the html element is showing `selected='selected'`.I has been try submit the record, endpoint not getting any data from it, Any way to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Issue solved. Its because of $("#id").attr('seletected','selected') not updating the properties to the latest one. Use prob() instead of use attr() to solve this issue.